# How to pass dropdown value to controller using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I need to pass a value from a dropdown list to a controller using ajax. Here's my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <input class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="btnDropDownCabang" name="btnDropDownCabang"
                    value="Pilih Salah Satu" type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="width:250px">
                Pilih Salah Satu
            <ul class="dropdown-menu mh" style="max-height: 250px; overflow-y: auto;" id="dropDownMenu"
                aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1" style="width:250px;">
                @foreach($cabang['data'] as $listCabang)
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{$listCabang->cab_kodecabang}}
                            - {{$listCabang->cab_namacabang}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
```

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'monitoring_plano/public/laporan/test',
                    data: {
                        'btnDropDownCabang': kodeCabang,
                    },
                    success: function (Response) {
                        alert(Response)
                    }
                })
```

```
public function test(Request $request)
    {

        $kodeCabang = $request->request->get('btnDropDownCabang');

        dd($kodeCabang);

    }
```

When I run it, it returns null. Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop down value isn't passed to the controller using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344870/drop-down-value-isnt-passed-to-the-controller-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

in dropdown-item you can create as below

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-kode="{{ $listCabang->cab_kodecabang }}">
```

and then in javascript like this.

```
$('body').on('click', '.dropdown-item', function() {
    let kodeCabang = $(this).attr('data-kode');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'monitoring_plano/public/laporan/test',
        data: {
            'btnDropDownCabang': kodeCabang,
        },
        success: function (Response) {
            alert(Response)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, still null @Aris Munandar

Comment: in controller $request->btnDropDownCabang

Comment: do you mean $request->request->get('btnDropDownCabang')? @Aris Mundandar. I did that already, still the same result