# Drop down value isn't passed to the controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, web

I need to pass a value from a dropdown list to a controller using ajax. But apparently, it doesn't work. The value shows null. I need to pass the value of `$kodeCabang` to a controller. How do I do this job?

The HTML code is as follows:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="btnDropDownCabang" name="btnDropDown" value="Pilih Salah Satu"
        type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="width:250px">
        Pilih Salah Satu
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu mh" style="max-height: 250px; overflow-y: auto;" id="dropDownMenu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1" style="width:250px;">

        @foreach($cabang['data'] as $listCabang)
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-kode="{{ $listCabang->cab_kodecabang }}"
                    data-nama="{{ $listCabang->cab_namacabang }}">
                    {{$listCabang->cab_kodecabang}} - {{$listCabang->cab_namacabang}}
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

</div>
```

The jQuery code is as follows:

```js
let kodeCabang = ""
let namaCabang = ""
$('body').on('click', '.dropdown-item', function () {
    namaCabang = $(this).attr('data-nama')
    $("#btnDropDownCabang").val($(this).attr('data-kode'))
    $("#btnDropDownCabang").html(kodeCabang + '-' + namaCabang + '&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>');
    kodeCabang = $("#btnDropDownCabang").val()
    //alert(kodeCabang + namaCabang)
    //alert(kodeCabang)
})
```

Ajax request is as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'monitoring_plano/public/laporan/test',
    data: {
        'btnDropDown': kodeCabang,
    },
    success: function (Response) {
        alert(Response)
    }
})
```

The controller is as follows:

```js
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $kodeCabang = $request - > request - > get('btnDropDown');
    dd($kodeCabang);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should show your ajax request in your code

then you can retrieve the value in controller

```
$request->input('btnDropDown');
```

```js
let kodeCabang = ""
let namaCabang = ""
$('body').on('click', '.dropdown-item', function () {
                                kodeCabang = $(this).attr('data-kode')
                namaCabang = $(this).attr('data-nama')
                $("#btnDropDownCabang").val(kodeCabang)
                $("#btnDropDownCabang").html(kodeCabang + '-' + namaCabang + '&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>');
                kodeCabang = $("#btnDropDownCabang").val()
                console.log(kodeCabang);
                //alert(kodeCabang + namaCabang)
                //alert(kodeCabang)
            })
            
$('#btnDropDownCabang').on('click' , function (){
    console.log(kodeCabang);
  // Ajax Call
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="btnDropDownCabang" name="btnDropDown"
                    value="Pilih Salah Satu" type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="width:250px">
                Pilih Salah Satu
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropDownMenu"
                >
                <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                           data-kode="abc"
                           data-nama="asd">
                            abc - asd
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                           data-kode="def"
                           data-nama="zxc">
                            def - zxc
                        </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                           data-kode="qwe"
                           data-nama="tyu">
                            qwe - tyu
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I've edited my question, is there anything wrong with my ajax request? @freddylauhk

Comment: Try to use `$request->input('btnDropDown');` instead of `$request->request->get('btnDropDown');` or use `$request->post();` to get all the post data

Comment: yup, did that. Still null

Comment: How you trigger the ajax call, because I can read `kodeCabang` value before the ajax call